# chrome filesystem - rename a directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

In the new chrome filesystem api, how do I rename a directory?

moveTo() on the directory itself doesn't seem to work, and I don't want to iterate over all the files in the directory.

Is there a simple way to just rename it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, can you give some more information about what sort of error you are encountering?

We get the parent directly from the entry and simply place the folder with a new name under the same parent.

Take note that this will fail, with an invalidmodification error if the new name is the same as the old, even if you change the caps in the name.

```
var test = function( entry, new_name ){
    entry.getParent( function( parent ){
        entry.moveTo( parent , new_name, function( new_node ){
            console.log( new_node )
            console.log( "Succes creating the new node" ) //We were able to rename the node
        }, function( error ){
            console.error( error )
            console.error( "Something wrong when finding the parent" )
        })
    }, function( error ){
        console.error( error )
        console.error( "Something wrong when finding the parent" )
    })
}

test( entry, "For the watch" )
```